# Django: how do I get a queryset of all users that are staff?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Django: how do I get a queryset of all users that are staff?

I'm trying:

```
staff = User.objects.get(is_staff=True)
```

but get a TypeError:

```
'User' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

get in a queryset is to get specific object value and is not iterable.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=2)
```

It gives you user object whose id is 2. There can only be 1 user with id 2

But in your case there can be many user with staff status

```
staff = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
```

This gives you list of staff. If you are looking for one object then use get if looking for list then use filter.

You can now use this in your template like this

```
{% for stf in staff %}
    {{stf.username}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter` instead of `get`.

```
staff = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is when using `staff = User.objects.get(is_staff=True)` that you can't be sure that it will return a single user (unless you know for sure).

Probably you might want to add more criteria to narrow down the options to one.

A more safer option is to user `filter`, which returns a list of users with matched criteria, without the need to exception-handle `objects.get` when things go against the expected

Answer (score 0):

get is used for returning a single object - not a queryset. It will give an error if it returns more than one entry from the database. In your case I am guessing it is returning a single User, and you are trying to iterate over that.

filter is what you want to use. It returns a queryset that can be iterated over.

```
staff = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
for person in staff :
    do stuff....
```